# Cast elements of vector to user defined type

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm looking for a good and modern way to cast all elements of a vector to a `cv::Point` or another user defined struct type:

```
struct ColorSpacePoint
{
    int X;
    int Y;
}

struct NewColorSpacePoint  
{
    int X;
    int Y;
}

std::vector<ColorSpacePoint> points{ColorSpacePoint{2,3}, ColorSpacePoint{9,6}};

std::vector<NewColorSpacePoint> = ...
std::vector<cv::Point> = ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a conversion operator to `ColorSpacePoint`:

```
struct ColorSpacePoint
{
    int X;
    int Y;
    operator NewColorSpacePoint() { return {X,Y}; }
};
```

Or a non-explicit constructor to `NewColorSpacePoint`:

```
struct NewColorSpacePoint  
{
    int X;
    int Y;
    NewColorSpacePoint (const ColorSpacePoint& rhs) : X{rhs.X}, Y{rhs.Y} {}
};
```

This would let you just use the `std::vector` range constructor:

```
std::vector<NewColorSpacePoint> new_points {points.begin(), points.end()};
```

---

If you would rather not use implicit conversions, you could make a free function and use `std::transform`:

```
NewColorSpacePoint to_new_color (const ColorSpacePoint& csp) {
    return {csp.X,csp.Y};   
}

std::vector<NewColorSpacePoint> new_points;
new_points.reserve(points.size());
std::transform(points.begin(), points.end(),
               std::back_inserter(new_points), to_new_color);
```

Comment: +1 for the transform option -- in my opinion this is the way to go. It allows the classes to remain more encapsulated and less complex; updating your class types later wouldn't require editing each class that converts to another

Answer (score 1):

Add conversion operator from `ColorSpacePoint` to `NewColorSpacePoint` and `cv::Point`, such as:

```
struct NewColorSpacePoint  
{
    int X;
    int Y;
};

struct ColorSpacePoint
{
    int X;
    int Y;
    operator NewColorSpacePoint() { return {X, Y}; }
};
```

then use the [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) of `std::vector` which takes a range of iterator as parameter:

```
std::vector<ColorSpacePoint> points{ColorSpacePoint{2,3}, ColorSpacePoint{9,6}};
std::vector<NewColorSpacePoint> new_points(points.begin(), points.end());
```

Or use [`std::vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert):

```
std::vector<NewColorSpacePoint> new_points;
new_points.insert(new_points.end(), points.begin(), points.end());
```